# Parse server name from UNC path using Perl

Tags: perl, samba

I'm looking for a way in Perl to get the server name from a UNC path when it is in either of the following formats:

`$unc = '//server.domain.com/share';`

`$unc = '\\\\server.domain.com\\share';`

Comment: So you just want `server` from these strings?

Comment: server.domain.com...sorry for confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for my $unc ('//server.domain.com/share', '\\\\server.domain.com\\share') {
    my ($server) = $unc =~ m{([^/\\]+)};
    print $server, "\n";
}
```

**output**

```
server.domain.com
server.domain.com
```

Comment: +1 So the user can accept your answer and I can delete mine since it is so inherently incorrect.